# Stuck Between "OOM" Error and "NaN loss during training" Error When Adjusting Batch Size

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, gpu, ram

I'm new to Tensorflow!
I'm trying to train an object detection model using a 8GB 3060ti FE GPU using Tensorflow1 (not 2) Version is 1.15.5. I am doing Tensorflow 1 because I know the ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized model works for my very old Android Device.

The problem I'm running into is with a batch size of 16, I get an OOM Error (Out Of Memory). The universal fix online is to lower batch size. When I do this, I get different error of "NaN loss during training." The universal fix for this is to increase batch size. I'm suck in this loop. I've also tried a batch size of every number between 8-16 and all give one of the two errors.

PC specs
i7-3770 CPU
16 GB DDR3 system RAM
1TB SSD
GeForce RTX 3060 Ti GPU
Windows 10

I am training with this Repo: https://github.com/ssysm/FTC-TFoD
Following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_tFzuxQ-FM&t=233s

pipeline.config file:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_mobilenet_v2"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.99999989895e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.0299999993294
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.999700009823
          center: true
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000475
          train: true
        }
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.99999989895e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.0299999993294
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.999700009823
            center: true
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000475
            train: true
          }
        }
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.800000011921
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.20000000298
        max_scale: 0.949999988079
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.333299994469
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993923e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.600000023842
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.990000009537
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 8
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.00400000018999
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.949999988079
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.899999976158
      decay: 0.899999976158
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:/Users/tnfal/TF-FTC-Master/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco_2019_01_03/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 30000
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "C:/Users/tnfal/TF-FTC-Master/train_data/label.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:/Users/tnfal/TF-FTC-Master/train_data/train-??.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 20
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "C:/Users/tnfal/TF-FTC-Master/train_data/label.pbtxt"
  shuffle: true
  num_readers: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:/Users/tnfal/TF-FTC-Master/train_data/eval-??.record"
  }
}
graph_rewriter {
  quantization {
    delay: 48000
    weight_bits: 8
    activation_bits: 8
  }
}
```

I'm using model_main.py with minimal changes:

```
# Copyright 2017 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================
"""Binary to run train and evaluation on object detection model."""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from absl import flags

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import estimator as tf_estimator

from object_detection import model_lib
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=1)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

#session = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))


sess = tf.Session(config=config)

flags.DEFINE_string(
    'model_dir', None, 'Path to output model directory '
    'where event and checkpoint files will be written.')
flags.DEFINE_string('pipeline_config_path', None, 'Path to pipeline config '
                    'file.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_train_steps', None, 'Number of train steps.')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('eval_training_data', False,
                     'If training data should be evaluated for this job. Note '
                     'that one call only use this in eval-only mode, and '
                     '`checkpoint_dir` must be supplied.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('sample_1_of_n_eval_examples', 1, 'Will sample one of '
                     'every n eval input examples, where n is provided.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples', 5, 'Will sample '
                     'one of every n train input examples for evaluation, '
                     'where n is provided. This is only used if '
                     '`eval_training_data` is True.')
flags.DEFINE_string(
    'checkpoint_dir', None, 'Path to directory holding a checkpoint.  If '
    '`checkpoint_dir` is provided, this binary operates in eval-only mode, '
    'writing resulting metrics to `model_dir`.')
flags.DEFINE_boolean(
    'run_once', False, 'If running in eval-only mode, whether to run just '
    'one round of eval vs running continuously (default).'
)
flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'max_eval_retries', 0, 'If running continuous eval, the maximum number of '
    'retries upon encountering tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError. If negative, '
    'will always retry the evaluation.'
)

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


def main(unused_argv):
  flags.mark_flag_as_required('model_dir')
  flags.mark_flag_as_required('pipeline_config_path')
  config = tf_estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir)

  train_and_eval_dict = model_lib.create_estimator_and_inputs(
      run_config=config,
      pipeline_config_path=FLAGS.pipeline_config_path,
      train_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps,
      sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_examples,
      sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=(
          FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples))
  estimator = train_and_eval_dict['estimator']
  train_input_fn = train_and_eval_dict['train_input_fn']
  eval_input_fns = train_and_eval_dict['eval_input_fns']
  eval_on_train_input_fn = train_and_eval_dict['eval_on_train_input_fn']
  predict_input_fn = train_and_eval_dict['predict_input_fn']
  train_steps = train_and_eval_dict['train_steps']

  if FLAGS.checkpoint_dir:
    if FLAGS.eval_training_data:
      name = 'training_data'
      input_fn = eval_on_train_input_fn
    else:
      name = 'validation_data'
      # The first eval input will be evaluated.
      input_fn = eval_input_fns[0]
    if FLAGS.run_once:
      estimator.evaluate(input_fn,
                         steps=None,
                         checkpoint_path=tf.train.latest_checkpoint(
                             FLAGS.checkpoint_dir))
    else:
      model_lib.continuous_eval(estimator, FLAGS.checkpoint_dir, input_fn,
                                train_steps, name, FLAGS.max_eval_retries)
  else:
    train_spec, eval_specs = model_lib.create_train_and_eval_specs(
        train_input_fn,
        eval_input_fns,
        eval_on_train_input_fn,
        predict_input_fn,
        train_steps,
        eval_on_train_data=False)

    # Currently only a single Eval Spec is allowed.
    tf_estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

Errors in full:

NaN loss Error

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Model diverged with loss = NaN.
E0109 19:13:41.056800 23808 basic_session_run_hooks.py:760] Model diverged with loss = NaN.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\models\research\object_detection\model_main.py", line 121, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\models\research\object_detection\model_main.py", line 117, in main
    tf_estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\training.py", line 473, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\training.py", line 613, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\training.py", line 714, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1195, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1494, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 754, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1259, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1360, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1345, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1426, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "C:\Users\tnfal\.conda\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 761, in after_run
    raise NanLossDuringTrainingError
tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.
```

OOM:

```
2023-01-09 18:55:57.068293: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 5914624 totalling 5.64MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.068373: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 12 Chunks of size 6144000 totalling 70.31MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.068455: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 2 Chunks of size 8192000 totalling 15.63MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.068536: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 14 Chunks of size 8640000 totalling 115.36MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.068617: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 56 Chunks of size 8871936 totalling 473.81MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.068698: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 21 Chunks of size 13307904 totalling 266.52MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.068779: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 14870528 totalling 14.18MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.068863: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 2 Chunks of size 17280000 totalling 32.96MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.068970: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 35 Chunks of size 17743872 totalling 592.27MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.069077: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 6 Chunks of size 23040000 totalling 131.84MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.069181: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 24104448 totalling 22.99MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.069285: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 25224192 totalling 24.06MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.069389: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 7 Chunks of size 34560000 totalling 230.71MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.069492: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 14 Chunks of size 46080000 totalling 615.23MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.069596: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 21 Chunks of size 51840000 totalling 1.01GiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.069700: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 7 Chunks of size 138240000 totalling 922.85MiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.069802: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:921] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 4.79GiB
2023-01-09 18:55:57.069904: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:923] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 5153567488 memory_limit_: 5153567539 available bytes: 51 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 10307135488
2023-01-09 18:55:57.070014: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:929] Stats:
Limit:                  5153567539
InUse:                  5145408768
MaxInUse:               5145409280
NumAllocs:                    5610
MaxAllocSize:            965214208

2023-01-09 18:55:57.070325: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:424] ****************************************************************************************************
2023-01-09 18:55:57.070443: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at fake_quant_ops.cc:242 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[16,19,19,576] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

I have already tried a system reboot, relabeling all training images, lowering image quality from 1080p-460p, deleting all info in the "saved_model"/checkpoint folder, and decreasing training rate.

I would hope that it would just run the model training at decent speed compared to CPU (which I did get working)

Comment: Can you upload onto Kaggle or Google Colab? I need to be able to see your code.

Comment: @TomLin sorry for not adding at least my training script. That has now been added to this form question. Adding everything to Google Colab would be time consuming, but I can do that tonight if you need to see full code (although model_main.py is almost all I use to train). I've also been able to get to a batch size of 16 without an OOM error, but I'm still getting the NaN loss error with a 16 batch. Any ideas? (thank you so much for your help and very sorry for my late reply)